# How to capture current set of classes used on an element

Tags: cypress

I have two elements on the page: `button1` and `button2`. One of them has class `active` set on an initial load.

I want to grab `button1` and check if `active` is set. If set, then for my tests I want to use `button2`, if not I stick with `button1`.

For my test, I need to test the switch action between two buttons, hence why I need to use the button which is not an active one.

Each button does have a text, i.e. `<div class="active" data-cy="button1">Button 1</div>`, so I was also thinking that maybe a different option would be to grab a `button1` with class `active` set and check if it exists? Not sure if that is possible...

How can the above be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to avoid conditional processing in the test, try to use a selector that targets what you want.

Given

```html
<button class="active">Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

use a `:not()` selector

```js
cy.get('button:not(.active)')
  .should('have.text', 'Button 2')
```

If there's other button, also not active but not wanted,

```html
<button class="active">Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Ignore me</button>
```

you can add a filter

```js
cy.get('button:not(.active)')
  .filter((index, button) => ['Button 1', 'Button 2'].includes(button.innerText))
  .should('have.text', 'Button 2')
```

If you really meant the active attribute,

```html
<button active>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

```js
cy.get('button:not([active])')
  .should('have.text', 'Button 2')
```

Comment: I totally get you about `conditional processing`. The data used for e2e test is not resettable at this stage which makes state control a pain. I may have to just bite a bullet and add an `after()` call to manually call an endpoint to reset a state of an entity that I am dealing with :S